# Dictionary value then key iteration

Tags: c#, dictionary

If I use a dictionary as follows (NB: The dictionary will not change after initialization)

```
public static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> mapColumns = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"IDCode", "EmployeeUID"},
        {"firstName", "Name"},
        {"lastname", "Surname"}
    };
    //Key: datatable field name (source data) - from a flat file (so no concerns about injection etc)
    //Value: destination table field names

    DataTable sourceData = ReadFromFile(@"\\server\shares\staff.csv");

    StringBuilder tsql = new StringBuilder(1024);
    tsql.AppendLine("insert into staffdata (");
    foreach (var value in mapColumns.Values)
    {
        tsql.Append($"{value},");
    }
    tsql.Length--;
    tsql.Append(") values");

    foreach (DataRow row in sourceData.Rows)
    {
        tsql.AppendLine().Append("(");
        foreach (string key in mapColumns.Keys)
        {
            tsql.Append($"'{row[key]}',");
        }
        tsql.Length--;
        tsql.Append("),");
    }
    tsql.Length--;

    InsertIntoDatabase(tsql.ToString());
}
```

I know that dictionary keyvalue pairs ordering is undeterministic, so the order the pairs are inserted is not necessarily maintained.
That is not a problem in the slightest.

**Is it therefore possible that the order of the pairs could get "shuffled" up between the Value iteration and then Key Iteration?**

I am trying to fully understand how the undetermined ordering of dictionary iteration works

For example - source data

```
IDCode FirstName LastName
A104   Joe       Soap
Q187   Martin    Smith
```

I expect (and am happy with):

```
EmployeeUID Name    Surname
Q187        Martin  Smith
A104        Joe     Soap
```

However, could it potentially insert as: (KeyValue pairs change order after Value iteration)

```
EmployeeUID Name    Surname
Soap        Joe     A104
Smith       Martin  Q187
```

I have run my own tests, and have not found that they change, but maybe in 1000000 iterations I got "lucky" or my tests were flawed in some way

Comment: The order of the dictionary might change if you modify it, that means on adding or removing, otherwise the order(the [enumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.enumerator?view=net-8.0)) is stable.

Comment: If you need guaranteed sort order, use a SortedDictionary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-8.0

Comment: Simply answer. Don't expect Dictionaries to have a meaningful ordering. The  implementation is written for fast access by Key. If there is no definition in the docs about ordering (there isn't) expect that with an implementation change the order my also change.

Comment: The [documentation for `Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=net-7.0) explicitly states that: `"The order of the keys in the Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection returned by the Values property."`. Therefore iterating the collection will NOT change the order of the items (but modifying the collection may well change the order).

Comment: Allow me to kindly remind that the comments are intended for asking for more information about the question, or for suggesting improvements for the question, not for answering the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Keys` and `Values` properties are [documented to be in the same order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=net-8.0#remarks):

> The order of the keys in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection` is unspecified, but **it is the same order** as the associated values in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection` returned by the `Values` property.

Mirrored by the [`Values` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=net-8.0#remarks):

> The order of the values in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection` is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection` returned by the `Keys` property.

Barring modifications (add/remove) between calls, of course.

This is because both properties iterate over the internal entries of the dictionary.

That being said: a dictionary is meant for lookup, not enumeration. So you'd better use a more fitting collection, like a list of tuples:

```
var mapColumns = new List<(string Title, string ColumnName)>
{
    ("EmployeeUID", "IDCode"),
    ("Name", "firstName"),
    ("Surname", "lastname")
}.AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: Thank you @CodeCaster. You have more than answered the question.
The ValueTuples would have been my first choice, however it is a script component for an SSIS package, so I do not have them available (using .net framework 4.5)

Comment: Alright, then you could still use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but I suppose you're looking for a succinct initialization syntax.

Comment: Sure, however it is still a great suggestion for others reading this post in the future

Comment: You could always create a little local function `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Kvp<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value) => ...` then use that in your initialization